# What are the alternatives of Module View Presenter(MVP) design pattern?

Tags: c#, .net

What are the alternatives of MVP design pattern in C# Web Application ? Why we should prefer it over MVP? How its different from MVP design pattern?

Comment: I don't understand this line...Why we should prefer it over MVP? How its different from MVP design pattern?

Comment: Neon-X:I am asking about the alternatives of MVP and why these alternatives are preferred over MVP design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is rarely ever a "right" choice for a pattern. Sometimes not even using a pattern at all may have its merits, or what you are doing is simply a yet unnamed pattern or hybrid of elements of patterns.

First, you must ask what kind of application are you developing and how the frameworks involved might benefits. Is it a desktop app? Mobile app? Web app? What language is it being written in?

A good example of the above reasoning is a C# WPF app. Given the nature of WPF, it certainly benefits from certain frameworks that can exploit binding context and separation of concerns more easily than others. MVVM is one example of an alternative to MVP that tends to work better than MVP here simply because the structure IMO is easier to use with XAML and databinding, however you certainly could make MVP work as well if you're a strong developer and the type of app was a good fit.

MVP itself even has sub-divisions which I'll quickly link to below as it is a large topic. A lot of the decision what to use even within these divisions is style and how you best see separation of concerns, modularity, reusability, coupling, etc. For example in MVP you can either directly bind the model to the view or properties of the model individually that you map on binding. You can also call methods on the presenter directly or raise events that it responds to more indirectly. The advantages/disadvantages are the same reasons as before, and in the case of events more specifically, how easy/hard is it to do things like debug, multi-thread, add new functionality, etc.

Honestly, at this point there's a blur because there's so many variations of these patterns. A lot of frameworks claim for example to be MVC, but are in fact not. The term MV* tries to help acknowledge this fact and is worth a google/read.

More directly, some alternatives to MVP are:

1. [Supervising Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html) - this is really MVP, just a split of the pattern
2. [Passive View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html) - the other side of the split of MVP
3. [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) - Usually used with WPF, but can be used in other desktop or web apps just as easily. Close cousins using something similar are Angular.js and Knockout.js.
4. [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) - similar to MVP, but more like its father.

As I alluded to earlier, there is no "preferred" pattern. It is your responsibility as a developer to figure out what works best for your task. MVC is wildly popular in the web world, while MVP (at least in terms of claiming you are MVP) is less so. In XAML/WPF/Databinding worlds, MVVM is probably the most common right now.

I'd ask myself the following:

1. What is my timeline? If I need this "thing" tomorrow, I may not have time for a pattern at all, better or worse because I won't have time to setup all the machinery and work around the idiosyncrasies where all these patterns eventually have warts/fail miserably without crazy code, meta-programming, layers of indirection, etc.
2. How will my code benefit? If the code is being reused in both the web and desktop, it may be possible to extract some  value from re-using things from these patterns like presenters/controllers/etc, but in my experience, this is largely unrealistic in anything but a trivial app. Other parts of the app are better candidates for re-use. Instead, I would look at things like testability, how easy it will be to add or change features, and if the pattern simplifies the most common tasks I need to do in terms of helping me grok the issues.
3. Size/Scale. Related to the previous point, if it's a large code-base, it is probably better to find some good patterns. In general, I would think of patterns more as a common language between developers rather than a panacea or magic pill. As your code grows bigger, this becomes more important to be able to execute and maintain parts of the application.
4. Tangible benefits if I choose a pattern. What do I get if I pick a particular pattern? This is more just a taste issue in combination with style. Do you prefer a more passive or active role in the parts? If you want something more active, MVC is pretty straight forward and has a lot of knowledge. If you want something more passive, the Passive View might be a good choice. If you want to do 2-way binding, MVVM might be a good choice. Do you have lots of complicated UI? Any or none might be a good choice.
5. Is there a great canned set of libraries you can use for your task (web example: Ruby on Rails, desktop: Prism/MVVM Lite) that uses XYZ pattern? If yes, maybe that will influence your choice for better or worse. I think the key here is to use what makes you productive.

Personally, I usually do use patterns, but I know when to be pragmatic and just get something done.

;tldr - You should be looking more at your problem and less at the pattern itself, then choose if you need a pattern, and then which if you do. There is no right answer.