# Is usage of MVP pattern will reduce the performance or not?

Tags: java, android

Usage of so many callback interfaces to achieve MVP pattern will reduce the performance or not? 
If it reduces the performance is there any alternate way to achieve MVP pattern,

please explain.

Comment: MVP doesn't excessively use callbacks, as far as I know. Reactive programming does, but yet I've heard stories of performance gains with RxJava

Comment: Please read this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601018/what-are-the-alternatives-of-module-view-presentermvp-design-pattern

Answer (score 2):

No. It is used to improve functionality and performance.

MVP is a way to separate background tasks from `activities/views/fragments` to make them independent of most `lifecycle-related` events.

For detailed study of MVP click [here](https://github.com/konmik/konmik.github.io/wiki/Introduction-to-Model-View-Presenter-on-Android).